# Finding highest vertex of 3d line with arcgis 10.5 and convert to point feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I have a series of 3D perpendicular lines running along an embankment. I need to determine the highest point along these perpendicular line. Each perpendicular line has a unique ID so that I can theoretically determine the highest point along each 3d line and join them to create a ridge.

My first problem is how to determine and extract the highest vertex of each 3D line and convert to point. I have 3d Analyst as well as the data reviewer. The Data reviewer can check for z-values but cannot determine the highest.

Comment: Convert feature vertices to points, add Z information, sort descending, delete identical using parent line I'd field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Feature vertices to points
2. 3d Analyst - Add Z information
3. Sort the points on the Z value
4. Select the point with the max z for each line id
5. Switch selection, delete selected.

You now have the highest point from each line, which you can join or use points to line tool to create your 'ridge'.